# Append query string to url

Tags: links

I have a page lets say Page1. Page1 will have a button called GoToPage2.

In the GoToPage2 button, I need to read the querystring and append its value to the url

For example: The GoToPage2 link is `/sitecore/content/Sitecore/Page2` and querystring is `?id=1234` so the GTOPage2 url will be `/sitecore/content/Sitecore/Page2?id=1234`

What is the best way of doing this?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Using SXA.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think javascript could be an answer..  add some code that checks your button(s) and adjust the url on the button.

Comment: Do I need to create a custom component ? If you have any example that would be helpful

Comment: And I need to use that button in few other pages as well. So, not sure adding javascript on every page would be an ideal solution

Comment: I'm no js expert, but I do think that if your button can be easily found (after the page is loaded) it should be fairly easy to find and adjust them without a big impact. Creating a custom component is also an option, but I think it might be overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Achieve using simple javascript snippet

---

Below snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button id="GoToPage2-Button">Get Go to page 2 url </button>
      <a id="GoToPage2-Anchor" href="https://url.com/page2-url">/page2-url</a>
      <script>
         $( document ).ready(function() {
             $("#GoToPage2-Button").click(function(){
         // Get all query string value
         var querySearch = $("#GoToPage2-Anchor").attr("href")+window.location.search;
         alert("Formatted url is: " + querySearch);
         });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Output**
[image]

---